# How to create a little loading spinner in placeholder (Glide)

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to create a little animated spinner then my picture is loading. But something goes wrong or maybe I'm blind and don't understand what I should change.
The first problem is the ViewHolder is large when the placeholder is "loading".

The second problem is a spinner is not rotating.
It will be a pleasure if someone can tell me where I'm wrong.

XML:

```xml
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="720">

<shape
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/cesar_blue_69cff7"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/storeItemImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:src="@drawable/enter_2_car" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/storeItemText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="someText" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Java:

```java
with(containerView) {
    GlideApp.with(containerView)
            .load("https://i.picsum.photos/id/688/5000/5000.jpg")
            .override(290, 78)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_circle)
            .into(storeItemImage)
}
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If it isn't really necessary to use **custom drawable**, then there is already a `CircularProgressDrawable` class solely for this kind of purpose. You can create its objects, change its different properties and use it as the **placeholder** with Glide. An example code may look like this :

```
    // create a ProgressDrawable object which we will show as placeholder
    CircularProgressDrawable drawable = new CircularProgressDrawable(this);
    drawable.setColorSchemeColors(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorAccent);
    drawable.setCenterRadius(30f);
    drawable.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    // set all other properties as you would see fit and start it
    drawable.start();

    // now set the drawable as placeholder in glide
    GlideApp.with(containerView)
                .load("https://i.picsum.photos/id/688/5000/5000.jpg")
                .override(290, 78)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(drawable)
                .into(storeItemImage);
```

Comment: you should change setColorSchemes to drawable.setColorSchemes(
   ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary),
   ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
   ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent)
)